# Catch double tap events on new Google Maps Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I've got a MapFragment (Google Maps API V2). I'd like to catch the double tap but I didn't find a solution until now. I tried this thing now but it doesn't work:

```
Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
f.getView().setOnTouchListener(this);
map = ((MapFragment) f).getMap();
```

I tried to catch the click event on the map but if use `ViewConfiguration.getDoubleTapTimeout()` to check if it's really a double tap I miss it. I think it's due to real behaviour of click listener, it was really a workaround. Any tips?

Comment: @JAPS No. I changed strategy because I saw that the double tap is a built-in feature to do the zoom. So I don't know if it exists a solution, however it can be strange for the user associate an action to a well known built-in action of maps in my opinion, it could be not user friendly.

Comment: Actually I only need on touch event but what happens is when user doubleTap the map map zooms and the logic i have written for onTouch also executes twice which is what I want to handle.

Comment: have you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](http://stillalivedeveloper.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/how-to-implement-double-click-listener.html) details an implementation based on GestureDetector.

Comment: This implementation is not applicable in my case because I'm talking about a mapfragment not a mapview.